# Getting undefined ngModel in Ionic AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm writing a HTML web app using `Ionic`. While trying to bind an `input` element to a `$scope` var, I'm getting undefined.

SignupCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('SUSU.controllers', [])
.controller('SignupCtrl',
    function ($scope) {

        /* Form entries */
        $scope.signupForm = {
            email: "",
            emailConfirm: ""
        };
});
```

signup.html:

```
 <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="signupForm.email">
 </label>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('SUSU', ['ionic','SUSU.controllers'])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
// Set and define states
$stateProvider
    ....
    .state('tabs.signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        views: {
            'login-tab': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
                controller: 'SignupCtrl'
            }
        }
    });
```

While debugging I have noticed that the value of `signupForm.email` is undefined after inserting text to the email input. How can I bind those two and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using correct ng-controller around that label?

Comment: Why would he do that? He's intantiating it in the state view declaration.

Comment: controller:SignupCtrl how can i miss it. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Guys I can't believe I have wasted so much time about that...
It's the `type="email"` who caused the problem. Because of some reason it doesn't work. When I changed it to `type="text"` it worked fluently.

[Read more](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1006)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this, but one way to achieve what you want is to do the following:

In your signup.html add a ng-change to your input:

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="signupFormEmail" ng-change="updateEmail(signupFormEmail)">
</label>
```

Then in your controller add a method to $scope that will update your signupForm email property:

```
$scope.updateEmail = function(email){
    $scope.signupForm.email = email;
}
```

Comment: Well that's just too weird... Adding the `updateEmail` function and debuging it resulted an undefined `signupFormEmail` var. Maybe I'm using the wrong angular package?? I'm including this `Ionic` angularjs package : `<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: Sorry, have no clue what that issue could be. I've done almost the same thing before. I'm reviewing my code now and it looks exactly the same.